# Manga where the main character dies and gets reincarnated as his younger self and tries to save his village from the demon army or king

Tags: story-identification, manga

It starts with the main character on the battlefield on the verge of death trying to save his lover. He musters up the strength to defeat some soldiers and finds out she died and gives up and dies. He regrets his life and all the events that happened to him.

He is reincarnated as his younger self as a baby and through this second chance he tries to stop all the events that leads to his friends and family's deaths. He is skilled with magic and swordsmanship. He is not Ip from the start but has all memories and skills to get stronger. First he tries to save his village from the demon army that 16 years in the future I think. Also I think his father is the strongest swordsman or adventures.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for *[Shi ni Modori, Subete wo Sukuu Tame ni Saikyou he to Itaru](https://myanimelist.net/manga/121989/Shi_ni_Modori_Subete_wo_Sukuu_Tame_ni_Saikyou_e_to_Itaru_comic)* by Shiryu and Oota Yokan.

> Eric has had a hard life. At the age of 16, his village was overrun by monsters, who killed his friends and family. He soon became a soldier but failed to save the life of the woman he loved. In the end, he died on the battlefield, surrounded by the bodies of those who he couldn’t protect.
>
> When Eric wakes up, he finds himself in a baby’s body. Realizing he has been reincarnated, he quickly wonders what is going on before he gets another shocker: the man and woman who are raising him are in fact his previous life’s parents!
>
> That’s right - Eric was reincarnated but as himself. No alternate worlds, no skill trees, just his memories sent back to the moment he popped out of his mother. Armed with the knowledge of his past self, Eric vows to save everyone now that the universe has pushed the reset button for him.