# Fantasy manga where the protagonist's village is attacked on his sixteenth birthday

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, magic

I'm looking for a manga where the protagonist lives in a world of magic and his village ends up being attacked by a villain on his sixteenth birthday. After a while, he ends up dying, however he goes back in time to when he was born. In his new life, he ends up training and using magic to build a wall around his village.

Comment: Hi. Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 3):

This is *[Shinimodori: When I'm Reborn, I'll Become the Strongest to Save the World!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shinimodori-when-im-reborn-ill-become-the-strongest-to-save-the-world)*.

> Family, friends, and the girl he has vowed to always protect… Eric lost everything he loved and died miserably on the battlefield… until he finds himself reincarnated into an infant’s body! Is God pulling his leg, or is fate offering him a second chance to start over? Now, Eric is on a mission to become the strongest and make his old enemies pay, even if it takes him another lifetime to do it!

The protagonist's village is attacked the day after his 16th birthday. He alone survives, but everyone else is killed including his friends and family.

[image]

He lives on after this, getting stronger and meeting other people, until he is finally killed on the battlefield after failing to protect a woman. He then finds himself back as an infant, and takes the opportunity to become stronger.

He does not warn anyone of the impending monster attack, and instead creates giant earthen walls around the village on the day of the attack.

[image]

This was not known to him before, but the monster attack was instigated by a specific villain, a demon that wanted to use the village as a staging point for attacking the capital.

Comment: Also answered https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238962 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252564